# In my Spring Boot web application, how can I send an email containing html without a templating engine>

Tags: java, html, spring, email, spring-boot

I currently have a Spring Boot web application and I want to send an email that contains HTML so the email looks more pleasing. Currently I am using SimpleMailMessage.

I would rather not implement a templating engine solely for the purpose of sending a nicely formatted email.

All help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you do not need a template engine at all. it would be easier though (depending on your use-case of course). however, you might want to take a look at `JavaMail`-`MimeMessages` for sending html mails.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in fact using Spring Boot, then you've gotten a really great start for sending messages. Your code can be loosely based on something as simple as:

```
@Component
public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {

    @Autowired
    public JavaMailSender emailSender;

    @Autowired
    public MimeMessage mimeMessage;

    public void sendMessage() {
       helper.setTo("someone@abc.com");
       helper.setSubject("This is the test message for testing gmail smtp server using spring mail");
       helper.setFrom("abc@gmail.com");
       mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    }
}
```

A `@Configuration` that looks contains your template:

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public MimeMessage templateSimpleMessage(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "utf-8");
    helper.setText("<h3>Hello World!</h3>");
    return message;
}
```

And just configure your mail SMTP destination like so in your `application.yml`:

```
# application.yml

spring:
  mail:
    default-encoding: UTF-8
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    username: [email protected]
    password: secret
    port: 587
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true
    protocol: smtp
    test-connection: false
```

If you want to construct more advanced templates, use [Velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/). [See example.](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-compose-html-emails-in-java-with-spring-and-velocity/)